# How do I deliver a new build system in SublimeText3?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have built a sublimetext3 plugin. Now I have added a build tool. To use this build tool, the user has to go to Tools->Build System->New Build System.

I consider this an extra hassle for the user. Is there a way to package it and deliver it along with the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the `.sublime-build` file (and its dependencies like shell scripts) to the files in your ST package. Unless there's a conflict with another build system, the user can then build using the keyboard shortcut.

[Build Systems](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html)